# how to loop after specified number of rows in table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `<table id="table">`.

A user can add rows in this table when clicking `<button id="new">`.

A user can save by clicking `<button id="save">`

If a user adds more than 5 rows without saving data, then they should get an alert to save. This alert should be repeated in each 5 new rows.

I've tried this :

```
$('#new').click(function(){
  var count = $('#table tbody').children('tr').length;
  if (count > 4) {
  var y = confirm("you should to save your data!");
  if (y == true){
    $('#save').click();
  }
  else {

  }
});
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you've written? It seems like something like that should work.

Comment: and another more thing if i want to prevent user from saving if there are rows not filled at least one cell

Comment: it already working but in each new row , i need it after each 5 new rows.

Comment: you have missed closing curly bracket for `if (count > 4) {`

Comment: Yes i forget it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `>` operator, you should use the [modulo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators) operator.

So change your `if` to this:

```
if (count > 0 && count % 5 == 0) {
```

Comment: but please i have another issue , want to prevent user from saving if rows or at least one cell in each row not filled. can help?

Answer (score 0):

A different elegant way is the following:

```
$('#new').click(function(){

  var $newRow = $('<tr><td>new</td></tr>').appendTo('table')

  if ($newRow.is('table tr:nth-child(5n)')){
    alert('Alert')
  };

});
```